# Arduino Ethernet shield not receiving UDP packets correctly

Tags: arduino, udp, ethernet, adafruit

I'm using a [Adafruit Ethernet FeatherWing](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3201) plugged into an [Adafruit Feather 328P](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3458) and I want to send and receive UDP packets from a Python application.  I'm using the [stock Arduino UDP code](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/UDPSendReceiveString) just to see what I'm sending.  Here's my Python code:

```
def write_Arduino(self):
    sock_readresp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock_readresp.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock_readresp.bind((self.config["DEFAULT"]["THIS_IP_ADDRESS"], int(self.config["DEFAULT"]["RECEIVE_PORT"] )))
    sock_readresp.settimeout(.2)

    MESSAGE = struct.pack("30c", b'0', b'1', b'2', b'3', b'4', b'5', b'6', b'7', b'8', b'9',
                              b'0', b'1', b'2', b'3', b'4', b'5', b'6', b'7', b'8', b'9',
                              b'0', b'1', b'2', b'3', b'4', b'5', b'6', b'7', b'8', b'9')

    print("Message is {}".format(MESSAGE))
    sock_read = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock_read.setblocking(0)
    sock_read.bind((self.config["DEFAULT"]["THIS_IP_ADDRESS"], 0))
    sock_read.sendto(MESSAGE,(self.config["DEFAULT"]["ARDUINO_IP_ADDRESS"],int(self.config["DEFAULT"]["SEND_PORT"])))
    sock_read.close()
```

My settings are:

```
THIS_IP_ADDRESS = 192.168.121.1
ARDUINO_IP_ADDRESS = 192.168.121.2
SEND_PORT = 8888
RECEIVE_PORT = 32001
```

and I've updated the Arduino code to reflect that.  When I send this packet, I can confirm it through Wireshark on my PC

[image: Wireshark]

I seem to be sending exactly what I think I am.  A string of "012345678901234567890123456789" (Wireshark shows the ASCII characters in hex, [as seen here](http://www.asciitable.com/)).  However, receiving it on the Arduino looks like this:

```
Received packet of size 30
From 192.168.121.1, port 64143
Contents:
012345678901234567890123D6789
```

The 25th and 26th byte **always** show up like that, and I'm missing the actual data.  What could be going on here?

Comment: the example is wrong. it is `#define UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE 24` https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Ethernet/blob/6e9dffa64f6b0eb89607dbb5293dc33be82cc39e/src/Ethernet.h#L150

Comment: Juraj is correct.  We can close the question.